# Sybase LOAD TABLE Decimal separator

Tags: load, decimal, sybase, import-from-csv

How can I tell Sybase to use a comma as a decimal separator instead of a dot?

I have to load a CSV that contains numbers like these: 333,44 999,11 888,22 (commas)

I cannot find the correct parameter to use with the LOAD TABLE

Any ideas?

How I currently use the LOAD TABLE:

```
load table table_1(
    number_1    ';',
    number_2    ';',
    number_3    ';\x0d\x0a'
) from '/xxxx/xxxx.csv'
escapes off
quotes off
Notify 10000
WITH CHECKPOINT ON;
```

Format of the column:  decimal(21,6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have so far is to use a XSLT to preformat the CSV

Answer (score 0):

*Possibly* changing it in Windows Regional Settings might do what you need.